# How to append item on Tray context menu in renderer process?

Tags: node.js, electron, tray

I use electron and Tray like this in "main.js" :

```
  const Tray = electron.Tray
  var appIcon = null;
  appIcon = new Tray(iconpath);
  var contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
      { label: 'Quit', click:  function(){
          app.isQuiting = true;
          server.close();
          app.quit();
      } }
  ]);
  appIcon.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
```

How can I append an item to the tray context menu inside a page "test.php" ?